# How to set permissions of fields programmatically?

Tags: entities, users

Using [field permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module, How do I can set/edit permissions of fields to the roles? I took a look at its module but I couldn't find out how it stores its permissions in the database.

Comment: Field permissions are stored in `field_config`.`data` -- take a look at the BLOB.

Comment: depending on your needs, you could do it yourself, see here(https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/field_permission_example!field_permission_example.module/group/field_permission_example/7)

Comment: @Geoff I'm using field permissions module, So I want to get this done using this module

Comment: @LaTradia the `data` column is *Serialized data containing the field properties that do not warrant a dedicated column.*, I opened it's `.bin` file and it was just a few HTML codes. Do you know how does it work?